# jQuery Drop Menu Click not Hover

Tags: jquery

I'm trying get this drop menu to work with click instead of hover but I cant seem to get it to work. Any ideas anyone ?

```
// Drop Menu
$(".navigation ul ul, .shoppingbasket ul ul").css({display: "none"});
$(".navigation ul li, .shoppingbasket ul li").hover(function(){
$(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideDown(400);
},function(){
$(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
});
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing the word 'hover' with 'click'?(line 2)

Comment: @Guidhouse - That won't work, .click() only takes one handler, .hover() takes two -- see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

[**.hover()**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) takes two handlers, the first one is executed when your mouse enters, the second is executed when your mouse leaves. For this reason, simply swapping [**.hover()**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) with [**.click()**](http://api.jquery.com/click/) will not work, since [**.click()**](http://api.jquery.com/click/) only takes one handler that executes when you click. However, [**.toggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) can be used to bind multiple handlers to be executed on alternate clicks.

```
$(".navigation ul ul, .shoppingbasket ul ul").css({display: "none"});
$(".navigation ul li, .shoppingbasket ul li").toggle(function(){
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideDown(400);
  },function(){
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
});
```

[**Try it out here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/6WFEz/)

Also, it's hard to tell w/o the HTML, but [**.slideDown()**](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) will make the element visible, and you may want to use [**.slideUp()**](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/). So you might want to try something like this:

```
$(".navigation ul ul, .shoppingbasket ul ul").css({display: "none"});
$(".navigation ul li, .shoppingbasket ul li").toggle(function(){
    $(this).find('ul:first').slideDown(400);
  },function(){
    $(this).find('ul:first').slideUp(400);
});
```

[**Try it out here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/PPKvt/)

In fact, why not use [**.slideToggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/), which makes things more compact and allows you to use [**.click()**](http://api.jquery.com/click/)?

```
$(".navigation ul ul, .shoppingbasket ul ul").css({display: "none"});
$(".navigation ul li, .shoppingbasket ul li").click(function(){
    $(this).find('ul:first').slideToggle(400);
});
```

[**Try it out here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/ssEb5/)

Comment: Thank you reply I went a head and tried the sample codes and found the drop down links don't work, See problem here http://www.media21a.co.uk/clientlogin/benaiahmatheson/benaiah-matheson/

Comment: @Adam - don't have too much time right now, but the problem is that the links ARE working. You CLICK to drop down the menu, but this same CLICK also sends you to another page. You have to disable the default functionality for clicking the top level item (this is probably why it was originally working with hover and not click). gl - I may update more later when I have time.

Comment: another problem is when you have more sub ul.. this won't work.