# How to get the same functionality from jquery .click as .hover? Animation is working with .hover, but not .click

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm writing a accordion-esque and I have it animating as I want using hover, however, I'd really like it to work on click instead of hover - when I swap out .hover for .click, no animation happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

-Erin

This works:

```
$('#productslider div.rum').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({left:'90px'}, 500);
    $(".vodka").animate({left:'0px'}, 500);
  }, function(){
});

$('#productslider div.vodka').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({left:'-90px'}, 500);
    $(".rum").animate({left:'575px'}, 500);
  }, function(){
});
```

Nothing happens with this:

```
$('#productslider div.rum').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({left:'90px'}, 500);
    $(".vodka").animate({left:'0px'}, 500);
  }, function(){
});

 $('#productslider div.vodka').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({left:'-90px'}, 500);
    $(".rum").animate({left:'575px'}, 500);
  }, function(){
});
```

Comment: I think this answers it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718131/jquery-drop-menu-click-not-hover

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `}, function(){` from your click event this should be

```
$('#productslider div.rum').click(function(){
   $(this).animate({left:'90px'}, 500);
   $(".vodka").animate({left:'0px'}, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the second function, `click` takes only one parameter..

```
$('#productslider div.rum').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({left:'90px'}, 500);
    $(".vodka").animate({left:'0px'}, 500);
});
```